# Could not load type 'Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bundling.BundleContributor'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, abp

I'm trying to use the custom themes for ABP.IO from nuget, but when I install the package and then add the dependency for the modules, I get the below error when running the application.

```
Host terminated unexpectedly!
Volo.Abp.AbpInitializationException: An error occurred during ConfigureServicesAsync phase of the module Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.AbpAspNetCoreMvcModule, Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc, Version=5.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load type 'Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bundling.BundleContributor' from assembly 'Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bundling, Version=5.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Could not load type 'Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bundling.BundleContributor' from assembly 'Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bundling, Version=5.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
```

The built-in Basic them also never works, and I get a welcome page without a theme. Not sure what's happening, please see the attached image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUMQR.png)

I need your help.

Thanks

Comment: Probably your project version and ABP CLI version are different. Make sure both of them are the same version.